# how to make a bar significant between box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like this with several set in samples and different properties. I am trying to do statical analysis between the sets across the properties

data look like this

```
df<- structure(list(Sample = c("set1_sample1", "set1_sample2", "set1_sample3", 
"set1_sample4", "set1_sample5", "set1_sample6", "set1_sample7", 
"set1_sample8", "set1_sample9", "set1_sample10", "set1_sample11", 
"set2_sample1", "set2_sample2", "set2_sample3", "set2_sample4", 
"set2_sample5", "set2_sample6", "set2_sample7", "Set3_sample1", 
"Set3_sample2", "Set3_sample3", "Set3_sample4", "Set3_sample5", 
"Set3_sample6", "Set3_sample7", "Set3_sample8", "Set3_sample9"
), Property1 = c(-19.7, -20.1, -19.2, -20.4, -21.4, -20, -18.8, 
-17.4, -19, -19.4, -19.3, -18.2, -20.9, -18.2, -17.9, -17.3, 
-17.5, -17.4, -18.9, -20.2, -18.9, -19.1, -17.8, -16.9, -18.7, 
-18.1, -17.8), Property.2 = c(7.7, 7.5, 7.8, 7.9, 7.7, 7.4, 8.2, 
8.1, 8, 7.7, 7.7, 10, 8.5, 11, 10.1, 9.1, 10.4, 10, 8.7, 8.5, 
9.7, 8.6, 10.6, 9.9, 8.9, 10.4, 8.7), Set = c("set1", "set1", 
"set1", "set1", "set1", "set1", "set1", "set1", "set1", "set1", 
"set1", "set2", "set2", "set2", "set2", "set2", "set2", "set2", 
"Set3", "Set3", "Set3", "Set3", "Set3", "Set3", "Set3", "Set3", 
"Set3")), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to plot them all together in one plot and then compare between and within each set (with a star significant)

for example I tried to simplify first for one property but I could not do it

```
# Box plot for Property1 with statistical differences
ggplot(df, aes(x = Set, y = Property1, fill = Set)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("set1_sample1", "set1_sample2"),
                                 c("set1_sample2", "set1_sample3"),
                                 c("set2_sample1", "set2_sample2"),
                                 c("set2_sample2", "set2_sample3"),
                                 c("Set3_sample1", "Set3_sample2")),
              y_position = max(df$Property1),
              textsize = 4)
```

any idea?